# How to find out the size of a directory in adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

I want to find out storage usage of an app.
I can list file size in adb shell using ls command. But, I didn't find 'du' command in adb shell. Is there any command or tool that allows me to figure out the storage usage of a directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `du` in `/system/bin`. But you can push busybox to device, and use busybox's du.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to install busybox on android emulator?

Comment: Just grab the binary of busybox, push it to your device, cd to where you pushed it into, and execute something like `./busybox du`

Comment: Thanks. I found this link too: http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/14/android-busybox